# Why does this command work with os.system() but not subprocess.Popen()?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to delete a number of jobs from a q.  The command to delete the job is `qdel JOBid`.

Initially, I tried to use the subprocess module, but I got an error:
     #!/usr/bin/env python

```
 import sys, os, subprocess as sp

 lo = sys.argv[1]
 hi = sys.argv[2]

 lo = int(lo)
 hi = int(hi)


for i in range(lo,hi):
    print "i is %d"%i
    p=sp.Popen(['qdel %d'%i],stdout=sp.PIPE)
    #os.system('qdel %d'%i)
```

So this did not work.  The error I got was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "del.py", line 14, in <module>
p=sp.Popen(['qdel %d'%i],stdout=sp.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Then I commented out the subprocess line and used os and it worked immediately.  I think I don't fully understand the subprocess module

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os, subprocess as sp

lo = sys.argv[1]
hi = sys.argv[2]

lo = int(lo)
hi = int(hi)


    for i in range(lo,hi):
         print "i is %d"%i
         #p=sp.Popen(['qdel %d'%i],stdout=sp.PIPE)
         os.system('qdel %d'%i)
```

The above code worked flawlessly.  I just want to know why and what the advantages are of the subprocess module. Also, I am using a unix shell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), you can see that your call to `Popen` is wrong: you should pass not a single command, but an array of arguments:

```
p=sp.Popen(['qdel', '%d'%i],stdout=sp.PIPE)
```

Alternatively, as [sc0tt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11142562/929437) points out, you can use `shell=True`, but this has some disadvantages in more complex cases: you would have to manually escape all the variable data in the command in case it contains, for example, filenames with spaces or anything much more potentially harmful (like `;`)

Comment: Wouldn't you still be required to use `shell=True` though? If you don't specify `shell=True` doesn't Popen expect the first item in the list of arguments to be the path of the program to execute?

Comment: @sc0tt From [man-page for `execvp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv): The  functions  `execlp()`  and  `execvp()`  will duplicate the actions of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified filename does not contain a slash (/) character.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use shell=True on your Popen call.

```
p=sp.Popen(['qdel %d'%i], shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE)
```

Comment: So if shell was false, then where was it trying to execute the command?

Comment: @Chris2021 With `shell=False`, it just runs the process with [`os.execvp()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.execvp). With `shell=True`, it invokes your default shell and makes it execute the supplied string.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same issue. Using shell=True as one of the parameter solved my problem.