# PyTesser simple usage error

Tags: python, ocr

I've downloaded [PyTesser](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/) and extracted it.

I was in the `pytesser_v0.0.1` folder and tried to run the [sample usage](https://code.google.com/p/pytesser/#Usage_Example) code in the python interpreter:

```
from pytesser import *
print image_file_to_string('fnord.tif')
```

and the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pytesser.py", line 44, in image_file_to_string
    call_tesseract(filename, scratch_text_name_root)
  File "pytesser.py", line 21, in call_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

NOTE: I'm in `Ubuntu 12.10` with `Python 2.7.3`

can anyone help me understand this error, and what can I do to fix it ?

Comment: If you just copied the usage example, I suppose you don't have `fnord.tif`. Use an image on your disk and change the code accordingly.

Comment: `fnord.tif` is included

Comment: Did you load the PIL?

Comment: Possibly related:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142485/why-does-this-command-work-with-os-system-but-not-subprocess-popen

Comment: Oh, sorry then, my bad. You need to install tesseract. That's the file not found, the argument to `Popen` in `call_tesseract`. `apt-get install tesseract-ocr`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't as well documented as it could be, but if you are not on Windows you need to install the `tesseract` binary for your platform. On Ubuntu and other Debian based Linux distributions, `apt-get install tesseract-ocr`. Then you can run:

```
python pytesser.py
```

which uses the test files `phototest.tif`, `fnord.tif` and `fonts_test.png` to test the library.

Answer (score 0):

For beginners on windows to use pytesseract:

1. Open command prompt
2. Type: `pip install pytesseract` 
   (this will install pytesseract last version module on your python easily)
3. Go to this link and download and install tesseract-ocr engine:
   https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/downloads/detail?name=tesseract-ocr-setup-3.02.02.exe&can=2&q=
4. Now you are ready to use pytesseract

For more information and see code example check this link:
http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/